# Neo4j paths with filters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get a cypher that can give me routes and available seats for source to destination. Below is my graph setup

```
create (t1:Trip{id:"red"}), (t2:Trip{id:"blue"}), (a:City{id:"A"}), (b:City{id:"B"}), (c:City{id:"C"}), (d:City{id:"D"}) 
create (t1)-[:stop_at]->(a),(t1)-[:stop_at]->(b),(t1)-[:stop_at]->(c),(t1)-[:stop_at]->(d),(t2)-[:stop_at]->(a),(t2)-[:stop_at]->(b),(t2)-[:stop_at]->(c),(t2)-[:stop_at]->(d)
create (a)-[:red]->(b),(b)-[:red]->(c),(c)-[:red]->(d) create (a)-[:blue]->(b),(b)-[:blue]->(c),(c)-[:blue]->(d) 
create (b)-[:red_01{seat:40}]->(c),(c)-[:red_01{seat:40}]->(d)
```

I have two "Trip", "red" and "blue". The relationships created between nodes (stops) using "Trip" id are just the abstract links. I would like to look for trips which stops at "A" and "D" and I used following query which returns trips "red" and "blue".

```
 match (t:Trip)-[:stop_at]->(c:City) where c.id = "A" or c.id = "D" return distinct t.id
```

Then I would like to get the paths and I am using following query.

```
 match (t:Trip)-[:stop_at]->(c:City) where c.id = "A" or c.id = "D" with distinct t.id as id
 match (source:City{id:"A"})-[rel*]->(dest:City{id:"D"}) where all(item in rel where starts with id) return rel
```

It returns 36 rows which combines every possible paths. For example:

```
[(A)-[:blue]->(B), (B)-[:blue]->(C), (C)-[:blue]->(D)]
[(A)-[:red]->(B), (B)-[:red]->(C), (C)-[:red]->(D)]
[(A)-[:red]->(B), (B)-[:red]->(C), (C)-[:red_01 {seat:40}]->(D)]
[(A)-[:red]->(B), (B)-[:red_01 {seat:40}]->(C), (C)-[:red]->(D)]
[(A)-[:red]->(B), (B)-[:red_01 {seat:40}]->(C), (C)-[:red_01 {seat:40}]->(D)]
```

What I would like to get is as follow:

```
[(A)-[:blue]->(B), (B)-[:blue]->(C), (C)-[:blue]->(D)]
[(A)-[:red]->(B), (B)-[:red_01 {seat:40}]->(C), (C)-[:red_01 {seat:40}]->(D)]
```

The suffix "_01" means there is a sale for that date/time trip between two stops. For all the "red" trips, I would like to get only path that has maximum count of sales included. If we look  at above result, it will be line number 5. The "blue" trip does not have any sales on that day and so we will keep it in result.

Here is the neo4j console for your reference. Thank you very much for your help.

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=2sho3j

Ryan

Comment: Good question - thanks for providing sample datasets and describing your problem in detail. However, your third query snippet does not compile: `where all(item in rel where starts with id)` has something missing. The correct expression should read like `WHERE ... STARTS WITH ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is a step towards answering your solution:

```
match (t:Trip)-[:stop_at]->(c:City)
where c.id = "A" or c.id = "D"
with distinct t.id as id
match (source:City{id:"A"})-[rel*]->(dest:City{id:"D"})
where all(item in rel where type(item) starts with id)
return rel, extract(r in rel | type(r)) as reltypes
```

It returns:

```
╒════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════╕
│rel                         │reltypes             │
╞════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│[{}, {}, {}]                │[blue, blue, blue]   │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│[{}, {seat: 40}, {}]        │[red, red_01, red]   │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│[{}, {seat: 40}, {seat: 40}]│[red, red_01, red_01]│
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│[{}, {}, {}]                │[red, red, red]      │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│[{}, {}, {seat: 40}]        │[red, red, red_01]   │
└────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

However, I think we should improve the data model first:

- Using a suffix in the relationship type for signalling something that may change often (here, to signal if there is a sale) is a bad idea. I recommend to use relationship properties, e.g. `sale: true/false`, or adding the days of sale as a list (storing dates can be tricky: use timestamps, string, [APOC date/time support](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support) - whatever suits your use case best).
- You may also consider to store the colour of the route as a property, e.g. `(a)-[:ROUTE {colour: 'red'}]->(b)` (`ROUTE` should be as descriptive as possible, e.g. `TRAIN` or perhaps `CONNECTED_BY_TRAIN`).

So, back to your question (using your original data model): you can count the sales on a particular path using various approaches:

`reduce`:

```
match (t:Trip)-[:stop_at]->(c:City)
where c.id = "A" or c.id = "D"
with distinct t.id as id
match (source:City{id:"A"})-[rel*]->(dest:City{id:"D"})
where all(item in rel where type(item) starts with id)
return rel, extract(r in rel | type(r)) AS reltypes,
  reduce(
    noSales = 0,
    item IN rel | noSales +
      case type(item) ends with '_01'
        when true then 1
        else 0
      end) AS noSales
```

Or a bit simpler width `filter` and `length`:

```
match (t:Trip)-[:stop_at]->(c:City)
where c.id = "A" or c.id = "D"
with distinct t.id as id
match (source:City{id:"A"})-[rel*]->(dest:City{id:"D"})
where all(item in rel where type(item) starts with id)
return rel, extract(r in rel | type(r)) AS reltypes,
  length(filter(item in rel where type(item) ends with '_01')) AS noSales
```

Both return the following result:

```
╒════════════════════════════╤═════════════════════╤═══════╕
│rel                         │reltypes             │noSales│
╞════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│[{}, {}, {}]                │[blue, blue, blue]   │0      │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{}, {seat: 40}, {}]        │[red, red_01, red]   │1      │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{}, {seat: 40}, {seat: 40}]│[red, red_01, red_01]│2      │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{}, {}, {}]                │[red, red, red]      │0      │
├────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┤
│[{}, {}, {seat: 40}]        │[red, red, red_01]   │1      │
└────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

To get the most sales, you only have to sort and get the top result:

```
order by noSales desc
limit 1
```